# Not able to execute the program successfully, gives "Error: Address already in use"

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on Networking module,making connections with client ans server.
The Server code is as follows :

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.connect()
    print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print "from connected user: " + str(data)
        data = str(data).upper()
        print "sending: " + str(data)
        c.send(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The Client code is as follows:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = raw_input("-> ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print 'Received from server: ' + str(data)
        message = raw_input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

But not able to execute the program successfully, gives the error address already in use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command netstat -nlp and find out the above mentioned port in the list.You will find the same port and the corrosponding PID also, either kill that process by kill -9  or you can go to your respective code and change the port number.

Secondly,it's preferrable to use localhost instead of '127.0.0.1'.
And there's an issue in your server code as well, instead of this statement 'c, addr = s.connect()' you need to write this one ' c, addr = s.connect()'.You need too accept the incoming connection and then connect with it.You are missing the acceptance of incoming connection.